# importing auto_arima error in python, any fix or alternatives?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, forecast

i'm working a forecast model using auto_arima function from pmdarima.
while i try to import this function i got this error
all packages are updated
looking for a fix or alternative way to get auto_arima function

Error:

from pmdarima import auto_arima
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
     in ()
    ----> 1 from pmdarima import auto_arima

```
\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pmdarima\__init__.py in <module>()
     47 
     48     # Stuff we want at top-level
---> 49     from .arima import auto_arima, ARIMA, AutoARIMA, StepwiseContext, decompose
     50     from .utils import acf, autocorr_plot, c, pacf, plot_acf, plot_pacf, \
     51         tsdisplay
\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\__init__.py in <module>()
      3 # Author: Taylor Smith <taylor.smith@alkaline-ml.com>
      4 
----> 5 from .approx import *
      6 from .arima import *
      7 from .auto import *

\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\approx.py in <module>()
      7 import numpy as np
      8 
----> 9 from ..utils.array import c, check_endog
     10 from ..utils import get_callable
     11 from ..compat.numpy import DTYPE

\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pmdarima\utils\__init__.py in <module>()
      3 # Author: Taylor Smith <taylor.smith@alkaline-ml.com>
      4 
----> 5 from .array import *
      6 from .metaestimators import *
      7 from .visualization import *

\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pmdarima\utils\array.py in <module>()
      5 # Array utilities
      6 
----> 7 from sklearn.utils.validation import check_array, column_or_1d
      8 
      9 import numpy as np

\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>()
     80     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
     81     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 82     from .base import clone
     83     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     84 

\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>()
     18 
     19 from . import __version__
---> 20 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     21 
     22 _DEFAULT_TAGS = {

\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>()
      9 
     10 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
---> 11 from .validation import (as_float_array,
     12                          assert_all_finite,
     13                          check_random_state, column_or_1d, check_array,

\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in <module>()
     16 
     17 from ..externals import six
---> 18 from ..utils.fixes import signature
     19 from .deprecation import deprecated
     20 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning as _DataConversionWarning

ImportError: cannot import name 'signature'
```